# Replace gvimext.dll in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, gvim

**How can I get the "Edit with ... using tabs" functionality in gVim on Windows 8 (64-bit)?**

I'd like to swap out gVim's stock gvimext.dll for one that adds an "Edit with ... using tabs" option to Explorer's right-click context menu.

On Windows 7 (64-bit) I used to be able to download the DLL and swap it in by following [these instructions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1720). However, I can't get it to work in Windows 8.

- The stock installation's context menu (sans "... using tabs") works fine (without a restart)
- ...but after replacing the DLL the gVim context menu options disappear and the gvimext.dll no longer seems to even load. (Windows 8 was restarted)
- if I again replace gvimext.dll with a backup of the stock DLL, the context menu options remain missing and the DLL still seems to fail to load (Windows 8 was restarted, again)
- If I re-install gVim, the context menu items return (even without a restart)
- What is the difference here between Windows 7 (where swapping DLL's works) and Windows 8 (where swapping DLL's fails)?

Comment: I would direct this question toward the developer of gVim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

The gvimext.dll I wanted to swap in needed msvcr100.dll (the MS Visual C Runtime version 10), which my fresh install of Windows 8 was missing. Detailed info: [The PROPER way to fix msvcr100.dll, msvcr100d.dll or d3dx9_*.dll errors](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/186-combat-arms-help/459799-proper-way-fix-msvcr100-dll-msvcr100d-dll-d3dx9_-dll-errors.html).

I figured this out by opening gvimext.dll in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the [vim-dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-dev) and asking someone to help you create a custom, Windows 8 compatible DLL.